# something about stagefright codec input format in android

Tags: android, stagefright

i am using stagefright videoencoder to encode video in android 4.4;

```
sp<AMessage> format = new AMessage;
format->setInt32("width", 1080);
format->setInt32("height", 1920);
format->setString("mime", "video/avc");
format->setInt32("color-format", OMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
format->setInt32("bitrate", 1000000);
format->setFloat("frame-rate", 25);
format->setInt32("i-frame-interval", 5);
sp<MediaCodec> videoEncoder = MediaCodec::CreateByType(looper, "video/avc", true);
videoEncoder->configure(format, NULL, NULL,MediaCodec::CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
videoEncoder->start();
```

but when i called:

```
status_t err = gSpVideoEncoder->dequeueOutputBuffer(&bufIndex, &offset, &size, &ptsUsec, &flags, kTimeout);
```

i got:

```
err === INFO_FORMAT_CHANGED
```

next step, I called:

```
sp<AMessage> newFormat;
videoEncoder->getOutputFormat(&newFormat);
uint32_t width = 0, height = 0;
newFormat->findInt32("width", (int32_t *)(&width));
newFormat->findInt32("height", (int32_t *)(&height));
fprintf(stderr, "new width: %d, height: %d\n", width, height)
```

I got result:

```
new width: 1088, height: 1920
```

I am confused(not 1080x1920), whether i should provide new input frame(1088x1920) to videoEncoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Video coding requires the frame dimensions to be aligned to multiples of 16 i.e. macroblock dimensions. HD resolution i.e. **1920 x 1080** is a special case as 1080 is **not** a multiple of 16. The underlying encoder expects the client to provide an aligned boundary.

In this case, you could provide the data windowed as below. For `Luma`, you will have to align to a multiple of **16** and for `Chroma`, you will have to align to a multiple of **8**. The remaining pixels could be prefilled with **zeroes**.

**Please note**: If the encoder is capable of handling 1920 x 1080 as an encoding resolution, the output should be fine. If the encoder encodes with 1920 x 1088, you will observe a green band at the bottom of the picture in the generated bitstream due to the zero padding.

```
---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                   Luma                    |
|                1920 x 1080                |
|                filled into                |
|                a buffer of                |
|                1920 x 1088                |
|                                           |
|                Last 8 lines could         |
|                be filled with zeroes      |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
-----------------------
|        Cb           |
|   960 x 540         |
|   filled into       |
|   a buffer of       |
|   960 x 544         |
|                     |
-----------------------
-----------------------
|        Cr           |
|   960 x 540         |
|   filled into       |
|   a buffer of       |
|   960 x 544         |
|                     |
-----------------------
```